# Sound/song recognition?

Tags: audio, speech-recognition

I'm new to Raspberry Pi with essentially zero knowledge. I'm wondering if, with machine learning or similar, it is possible to identify a specific sound (say the first few seconds of a song). I've only been able to find speech recognition, and could not tell if a speech recognition application is able to recognize input from a song or if it exclusive to speech.

My end goal is to have a simple robotic-arm "flinch" as it recognizes a particular song or sound; what might a first step be in terms of Raspberry Pi sound recognition with or without AI?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad and opinion based. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed.